# Need help moving paddle in Breakout game for Java

Tags: java, processing, keylistener, key-bindings

I am making the game Breakout for my AP Computer Science class. I have done most of it, but I do not know how to use the arrow keys on a keyboard to move the paddle left and right. Can I get some help? I would appreciate it.

Here is what I have so far:

Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import java.util.random;

public class Main extends PApplet {

ArrayList<Brick> bricks = new ArrayList<Brick>();
ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
ArrayList<Paddle> paddles = new ArrayList<Paddle>();
Paddle paddle;
Brick brick;
Brick bricklevel2;
Ball ball;
Random g = new Random();



public void setup() {
    size(600, 600);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        brick = new Brick(100 + 100*i, 100, 10, 30, color(255, 0, 0), this);
        bricks.add(brick);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
        bricklevel2 = new Brick(100 + 100*i, 110, 10, 30, color(255, 0, 0), this);
        bricks.add(bricklevel2);
    }

    balls.add(ball = new Ball(250, 300, color(89, 700, 999), 20, g.nextInt(20)-10, 10, this));
    paddles.add(paddle = new Paddle(300 - 105, 500, 50, 500, color(500, 65, 800), this));



}

public void draw() {
    background(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < bricks.size(); i++){
        Brick brick = bricks.get(i);

        if (brick.isColliding(ball)) {
            bricks.remove(i);
        }
        brick.draw(); 
    }
    for(Ball b: balls){
        b.update(brick, paddle);
        b.draw();

    }
    for(Paddle p: paddles){
        p.update(paddle);
        p.draw();
    }


}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    PApplet.main(new String[] {"Main"});
}
}
```

Paddle Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import processing.core.PApplet;

 public class Paddle{
private int xPosition, yPosition, length, width, color;
private PApplet p;

public Paddle(int x, int y, int l, int w, int c, PApplet p) {
    xPosition = x;
    yPosition = y;
    length = l;
    width = w;
    color = c;
    this.p = p;

}

public void draw() {
    p.fill(color);
    p.rect(xPosition, yPosition, 210, 17);
}

public void update(Paddle paddle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public int getLeft(){
    int n = xPosition - 105;
    //System.out.println(n);
    return n;
}

public int getRight(){
    int n = xPosition + 105;
    //System.out.println(n);
    return n;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `KeyEvent` and `KeyListener`. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) tutorial from Oracle should help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Processing, you'd be best of read this little tutorial : http://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html

They explain how you can intercept a key press and then respond to it.